# Is there a Rails 3 version of the gem SMERF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been looking for a gem that will help build user generated forms.

I need to be able to allow users to define multiple fields like "checkbox" => value or "pulldown" => values as well as positon on the form itself for each.  This form could then be saved and other users could fill it out and that data would be saved and associated with that form.

[SMERF](https://github.com/springbok/smerf) I thought would help, but its not been updated for a very long time and I am using rails 3.

Comment: SMERF doesn't appear to be very hefty. You could probably hack out a Rails 3 compatible version in short time if you can't find a suitable replacement.

Comment: @coreyward I also found this one [dynamic_forms](https://github.com/tcocca/dynamic_forms).  But i really dont think my skill level is up to knocking it out for rails 3. Not yet at-least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough, I converted SMERF to Rails 3 a while ago. Not fully tested, so let me know if there are any problems.

http://github.com/ferrisoxide/smerf

Fair warning - this was my first attempt at getting a gem working with Rails 3. Bound to be crufty.

Comment: Thats great I will look into it. Now if i could only get this one working on rails 3 https://github.com/tcocca/dynamic_forms its exactly what i am looking for actually . :)